# Using LINQ, how to aggregate a collection to a specified type?

Tags: c#, linq

`Aggregate` lets you provide a custom function to run over `IEnumerable<T>` and return a `T`.
`Sum` lets you pull an `int` from each element using a custom function and then adds them all together.

But what if I want to do something like this thrown-together example:

```
struct S
{
 public int i;
 public int j;
}

int Aggregate(IEnumerable<S> data)
{
 int ret = 0;
 foreach(x in data)
 {
  ret ^ = Math.Max(x.i,x.j);
 }
 return ret;
}
```

As in I want to aggregate to a specified type using a specified function.
Does LINQ provide this or would one have to combine multiple LINQ operations?

Comment: `data.Aggregate(0, (total, next) => total ^ Math.Max(next.i, next.j))`?

Comment: you have `Aggregate<TSource,TAccumulate,TResult>`

Comment: Aha, I missed the overload. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of LINQ's `Aggregate` functions to do this:

`Aggregate<TSource,TAccumulate>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TAccumulate, Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate>)`

For example:

```
var aggregate = data.Aggregate(0, (acc, cur) => acc ^ Math.Max(cur.i, cur.j));
```

As described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__):

> Applies an accumulator function over a sequence. The specified seed
>   value is used as the initial accumulator value.

Comment: As Selvin points out in a comment, you might want to explicitly mention which overload this is as it can get pretty messy reading them all and understanding lamdas. Otherwise this is a nice answer, thanks

Comment: @Mr.Boy Thanks, I was *just* updating the link as you commented!